# Title in 2 rows with border down?

Tags: html, css

How do I put a border down in both rows and not just one?

[image: example]

Comment: Is just using text underline not an option? It seems to be what you are trying to achieve here. E.g. using `text-decoration` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Comment: @DBS how to add height to text decoration? I need 'fat' line like 4px?

Comment: There is a `text-decoration-thickness` property ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness)) though if you need support for some of the particularly old browsers you may need to look for workarounds/pollyfills.

Comment: @DBS nice man, thank you!

Comment: ```text-underline-offset``` property to adjust the spacing between line and the text